# Linux kernel : schedule() function in multi-processors system

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, schedule

Is there a difference between the ((performing)) of the schedule function in multi-processors system to it`s ((performing)) in uni-processor system ?

Answer (score 1):

Some things to consider:

1. If each processor run its own clock then scheduler can be invoked in different time independently on each core, or even set to tickless.
2. Each processor needs its own run queue.
3. Scheduler can take action to load balance and migrate tasks from a hot processor to less contended ones.

More information could be found in book Professional Linux kernel architecture Chapter 2.8.1 or by check Linux source code kernel/sched/* and search for those controlled by CONFIG_SMP marco, which is essentially the diff between SMP and non-SMP version.